# How do extract values from a label-value string in Excel VBA?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am trying to process a large amount of data in VBA (in excel).

I have thousands of lines of strings that look like this:

```
LABEL_PERCENT XXX.XX% LABEL_DATE mm/dd/yy
```

I have used split to process line-by-line (so I am looking at an individual string as defined above).  All of the lines have that exact formatting.  For each line, I'd like to extract the percentage, and date, for populating a spreadsheet.  How do I process the string in VBA, such that I can extract the values into two new variables?

Comment: If it is always the same then split on the `" "` and take the values from the array in positions 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using Split()? This function is how you could extract the four values, splitting on the spaces:

```
Dim str As String
Dim splitted As Variant

str = "LABEL_PERCENT XXX.XX% LABEL_DATE mm/dd/yy"
splitted = Split(str, " ")
Debug.Print splitted(1)    'XXX.XX%
```

splitted(3) will give you the date. You then might want to parse the values as a percentage and date.

Comment: So easy.  Occasionally I don't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks!